# Running a method after the initialize method

Tags: ruby

I would like to write some ruby code that runs after the initialize method is called. This code can be in a class or a module. How would I write this?

Here is an example of what I want:

```
class Base
  def after_init
    puts "after init"
  end

class A < Base # Option 1, use a class
end

class B < Base
  def initialize
    puts "in init"
  end
end

module MyMod
  def after_init
    puts "after init"
  end
end

class C
  include Module
end

$> A.new
=> "after init"
$> B.new
=> "in init"
=> "after init"
$> C.new
=> "after init"
```

What I definitely don't want to do is make an explicit call to `super`. Is there a way to do this? I don't care if it uses a lot of Ruby's reflective abilities. Thanks!

Comment: What do you have against `super`?

Comment: I'm writing a library that a user will use. The user will either extend the class or include the module. The added behavior depends on the state of the user's class being fully initialized. Having a requirement that `super` be called at the end of the user's class is too strict and will be prone to bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Base
  def after_init
    puts "Base#after_init"
  end

  def self.inherited(klass)
    class << klass
      alias_method :__new, :new
      def new(*args)
        e = __new(*args)
        e.after_init
        e
      end
    end
  end
end

module MyMod
  def after_init
    puts "MyMod#after_init"
  end
  def self.included(klass)
    class << klass
      alias_method :__new, :new
      def new(*args)
        e = __new(*args)
        e.after_init
        e
      end
    end
  end
end

class A < Base
end

class B < Base
  def initialize
    puts "B#initialize"
  end
end

class C
  include MyMod
  def initialize
    puts "C#initialize"
  end
end

A.new
B.new
C.new
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example class from which you could inherit:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    alias_method :_new, :new

    def new
      _new.tap do |instance|
        instance.send(:after_init)
      end
    end

  end

  private

  def after_init
    puts 'after_init'
  end
end
```

I thought through everything that could happen by overriding `new`, but this should be enough to get you started.

**Edit**: as a module:

```
module MyMixin
  def self.included(base)
    class << base
      alias_method :_new, :new

      define_method :new do
        _new.tap do |instance|
          instance.send(:after_init)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def after_init
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyMixin
end
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks. Is there any way to do this in a module? I tried something similar but I got an error saying there way no method `new` for `Class`.

Comment: You should look at @ArieShaw's answer as well, specifically where he includes `*args` for `new` (something I forgot).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, and it helped upblock me, but I awarded ArieShaw the answer since his is more complete and will be more helpful for future users. Thanks again :)