# How to call a method immediately after initialization in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have:

```
module Something
  class SomethingElse

    def initialize(args)
      @args = args
    end

    def some_method
      #stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way I can get some_method to run automatically right after intialize, but without calling some_method from within the initialize method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a method after the initialize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075010/running-a-method-after-the-initialize-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you allow to also define `initialize` in another module.

```
module Child
  def initialize
    super
    # ... some_method_stuff
  end
end

Something.prepend Child
```